# Options to update PDO Query

Tags: mysql

How i update this query?
I try get all category with more than 1 product, counting this products to show in her side, but my query is too slow (2s). How i do the same, if possible,  but more faster?

```
SELECT
    C.id, C.name, C.id_dept, C.cat_type, C.num_prod  
FROM
    (SELECT 
        C.id, C.name, C.id_dept, C.cat_type, 
        COALESCE((SELECT count(P.id) FROM Products P WHERE P.status = 1 AND P.promo = 1 AND P.id_cat = C.id ), 0) AS num_prod 
    FROM 
        Products_Cat C 
    ) C 
WHERE
    C.num_prod > 0 AND C.cat_type = 1 AND C.id_dept = '{IDD}' 
    ORDER BY C.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update PHP PDO**

```
$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `Products` set `name` = :name,  `id_dept` = :id_dept, `cat_type` = :cat_type WHERE status = 1 AND promo = 1);
//bind all parameters
$sql->bindParam(':name',$name);
.
.
.
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: Ajit Singh, i want list results and not update the database.